# xypic: Pasting Diagrams in LyX

Tags: lyx, xy-pic

I haven't been able to find detailed instructions on how to use `\compositemap` from the 2cell feature of xypic, and I want to make (relatively simple) pasting diagrams. In particular, I want to typeset the *whiskering* operation, where we have a diagonal double arrow between vertices of a commutative square.

Also, is there a way to reverse the direction of the double arrow in 2cells in xypic, in LyX?

[image]

Heeelp!

Comment: Would you be willing to use a more modern package?

Comment: Hmmm.. Ideally, I would like to stay with xypic - unless of course, I have no choice.

Comment: Do you have a picture, a link to an image, or even a hand-drawn image of the diagram you are trying to produce? Could you please add it to your question?

Comment: Certainly! Just a second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend `tikz-cd`, too. But here's a version for Xy-pic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix@C+3em@R+3em{
  V_1 \ar[r]^{\rho_1(g)} \ar[d]_{\phi} &
  V_1 \ar[r]^{\rho_1(g')} \ar[d]^{\phi} &
  V_1 \ar[d]^{\phi} \\
  V_2 \ar[r]_{\rho_2(g)} \ar@{=>}[ur]^{\phi(g)} &
  V_2 \ar[r]_{\rho_2(g')} \ar@{=>}[ur]^{\phi(g')} &
  V_2
}
\end{gathered}
=
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix@C+3em@R+3em{
  V_1 \ar[r]^{\rho_1(g'g)} \ar[d]_{\phi} &
  V_1 \ar[d]^{\phi} \\
  V_2 \ar[r]_{\rho_2(g'g)} \ar@{=>}[ur]^{\phi(g'g)} &
  V_2
}
\end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's one with shortened arrows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}

\newdir{S}{{}*!/-4em/@{=}}
\newdir{>S}{!/-4em/@{}*@{=>}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix@C+3em@R+3em{
  V_1 \ar[r]^{\rho_1(g)} \ar[d]_{\phi} &
  V_1 \ar[r]^{\rho_1(g')} \ar[d]^{\phi} &
  V_1 \ar[d]^{\phi} \\
  V_2 \ar[r]_{\rho_2(g)} \ar@2{S->S}[ur]^{\phi(g)} &
  V_2 \ar[r]_{\rho_2(g')} \ar@2{S->S}[ur]^{\phi(g')} &
  V_2
}
\end{gathered}
=
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix@C+3em@R+3em{
  V_1 \ar[r]^{\rho_1(g'g)} \ar[d]_{\phi} &
  V_1 \ar[d]^{\phi} \\
  V_2 \ar[r]_{\rho_2(g'g)} \ar@2{S->S}[ur]^{\phi(g'g)} &
  V_2
}
\end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you perhaps explain how to use the "compositemap" command

Comment: @Exterior No, I know nothing about `\compositemap` and the manual is cryptic as usual. I added a version with shortened center arrows anyway.

Comment: I have a related problem with a similar diagram. Should I make a separate question or edit this one?

Comment: Don't edit this one

Answer (score 4):

I know that you specifically asked for a `xy-pic` solution, however, here's a possibility using the more modern and powerful [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package:

[image]

The code:

% Although you specifically asked for a xy solution, here's a possibility using the more modern and powerfult [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large,row sep=large]
V_{1}
  \arrow[r,"\rho_{1}(g)"]
  \arrow[d,swap,"\phi"] & 
V_{1}
  \arrow[r,"\rho_{1}(g')"]
  \arrow[d,swap,"\phi"] & 
V_{1} 
  \arrow[d,swap,"\phi"] & 
V_{1} 
  \arrow[r,"\rho_{1}(g'g)"]
  \arrow[d,swap,"\phi"] & 
V_{1} 
  \arrow[d,swap,"\phi"]
\\ 
V_{2}
  \arrow[r,swap,"\rho_{2}(g)"]
  \arrow[ur,Rightarrow,"\phi(g)"] & 
V_{2}
  \arrow[r,swap,"\rho_{2}(g')"]
  \arrow[ur,Rightarrow,"\phi(g')"] & 
V_{2} 
  \arrow[ur, phantom, "{=}", midway] & 
V_{2} 
  \arrow[r,swap,"\rho_{2}(g'g)"]
  \arrow[ur,Rightarrow,"\phi(g'g)"] & 
V_{2}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll wait for a bit to see if someone provides an answer using xypic. If nothing appears, I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, and its different from the other examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\vcenter{\hbox{
\xymatrix@!0@=20mm{
V_1\ar[r]^{\rho_1(g)}\ar[d]_{\phi}\xtwocell[rd]{}<>{^\phi(g)\quad}&
V_1\ar[r]^{\rho_1(g')}\ar[d]_{\phi}\xtwocell[rd]{}<>{^\phi(g')\quad\ }&
V_1\ar[d]^{\phi}\\
V_2\ar[r]_{\rho_2(g)}&
V_2\ar[r]_{\rho_2(g')}&
V_2
}
}}
=
\vcenter{\hbox{
\xymatrix@!0@=20mm{
V_1\ar[r]^{\rho_1(g'g)}\ar[d]_{\phi}\xtwocell[rd]{}<>{^\phi(g'g)\qquad}&
V_1\ar[d]^{\phi}\\
V_2\ar[r]_{\rho_2(g'g)}&
V_2
}
}}
\]
\end{document}
```

You can also write `\drtwocell<\omit>{^\phi(g)\quad}` instead of `\xtwocell[rd]{}<>{^\phi(g)\quad}` but the advantage of the second one is that it can take any direction, and the first although its is simpler you have only `\··twocell`. As for reversing the arrows in a two cell the `^` symbol in there does the job. The white space `\quad` is the workaround of adjusting the label position that otherwise would overlap with the 2-cell. And the `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` changes the origin of the xymatrix to be the center of the box.